# CSS width:100% not fitting the screen

Tags: html, css, width

Im trying to make my footer to be at the end of the page, so I'm using position:absolute and bottom:0 to do this.
The problem is the background color will not be extended to fit the screen, so I tried using width:100% but now it has extra pixels

this is the example i created
http://jsfiddle.net/SRuyG/2/
(sorry it's a bit messy, i'm just starting to learn css)

I also tried the sticky footer from some tutorials i found but it's not working either.
So how exactly can I set the footer to the bottom of the page and the background fits the screen size?

Thank you

CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {     
    font: 13px/22px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;  
    background: #f0f0f0;  

} 

.contentWrapper{
     min-height: 100%;
     margin-bottom: -142px; 
}

.contentWrapper:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 142px; 
}

nav {
    background: #222;  
    color: #fff;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding: 10px 20px; 
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 4px #888888; 

}

#navBar li{
    display:inline;
}

#navBar li a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 25px;
}
#navBar li a:hover{
    background:#fff;
    color: #222;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 25px;
}

footer {
    position:absolute;  
    background: #222;  
    color: #fff;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding: 10px 20px; 
    bottom:0;
    width: 100%;

}
```

HTML:

```
<body>  

    <nav>  
        <ul id='navBar'>  
            <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>  
            <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>  
            <li><a href="#">link 3</a></li>  
        </ul>
    </nav>  



    <div id="contentWrapper">
        <section id="intro">  
        <header>  
            <h2>Intro</h2>  
        </header>  
        <p>Paragraph goes here, long and long paragraph, blah blah blah. Paragraph goes here, long and long paragraph, blah blah blah.
            Paragraph goes here, long and long paragraph, blah blah blah. Paragraph goes here, long and long paragraph, blah blah blah.
            Paragraph goes here, long and long paragraph, blah blah blah. Paragraph goes here, long and long paragraph, blah blah blah.
        </p>
        </section>  
    </div>

    <footer>  
            <section id="about">
                <header>
                    <h3>Footer</h3>
                </header>
                <p>some text here. </p>
            </section>
    </footer>  

</body>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using [`box-sizing: border-box;`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing0) to constrain the border and padding areas to the width of the `<footer>` - as the `padding: 10px 20px` rule is what's causing the scroll bar to appear.

```
footer {
    position:absolute;  
    background: #222;  
    color: #fff;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding: 10px 20px; 
    bottom:0;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SRuyG/4/

Answer (score 5):

Your footer is within the body, which is within the HTML. Since you haven't declared a width, it isn't going to expand any wider than it needs to. For your specific HTML, you should do something like this with your CSS:

```
body, html {
  width: 100%; // or body { width: 960px; } if you're using a fixed width
}

footer {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Ultimately, remember that any width set in a percentage is (almost) always going to be in comparison to the parent. 100% of a 50% parent is still 50%. 50% of a 75% parent is only going to yield 37.5% of the total viewport width.

Answer (score 3):

you can remove `padding: 10px 20px;` from footer and add `footer section{margin:10px 20px}`

http://jsfiddle.net/SRuyG/5/

Comment: This method is better than the accepted answer if you need to support IE7 or lower, which doesn't support the box-sizing property.

Answer (score 1):

try this..

remove these rules from the footer..you'll be fine

```
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
width:100%;
```

[updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/SRuyG/6/)

Answer (score 1):

From below css I have removed the padding property

```
footer {
        position:absolute;  
        background: #222;  
        color: #fff;
        list-style: none;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        bottom:0;
        width: 100%;

    }
```

and add this thing in ur css

```
 footer section
    {
        margin:10px 20px;

    }
```